# Can you identify these dresses

Tags: part-identification

Can you identify these monochrome slope/dresses? I looked in the curved slope section of bricklink but couldn't find them.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the part with item number 36036, called [Lower Body, Skirt](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=36036) on bricklink.
[image]